# See missing CSS files with developer tools

Tags: google-chrome, web-development

Is it possible to with any Chrome or any other developer tools to see which CSS files link to in a page dont actually exist?

Comment: See the Web Developer Tools console for 404 errors of files. From the files look for **css** extension ending URLs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any browser's Developer Tools, if you switch to the `Network` pane, you'll see all requests made from the page. Look for red lines, those will be requests that failed. Of those, look for the ones that have a 404 (Not Found) Status. As the comments said, the ones ending with `.css` are the ones you like.

As a bonus, FireFox's Dev Tools have a filter at the bottom - choose "CSS" and you'll only see requests for CSS files - successful, or otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

In chrome developer tools on the network tab you can also filter for this

```
    status-code:404
```

to only get a list of missing resources

Comment: Filtering for that phrase removes all other results except 404's, the previous answers all involved manually looking through the whole list of resources, for the red ones - this is much more efficient.